# 'expression cannot be used as a function' in qt-signals / slot

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

this is my first entry here and i hope, i will make a well-formed, usefull question.

I do programming with qt since a moment and also did slots and signals with success - the also weird thing is, that it has been worked for a moment, but not anymore - no idea why.

I've done some searches on that error and it seems to be most-often cause of variables and functions with the same name (and on the error-part it will try the var as function). This is checked too but should not be the case.

It's a in-itself-closed qwidget and i just release my lines:

http://pastebin.com/TXXY1cT4

so the problems are the lines in settingwidget.cpp (downer on the paste):

```
connect(terminalCompleter, SIGNAL(textChanged()), this,SLOT(onNrOfLeds22()));
connect(this->nrOfLeds, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this,SLOT(onNrOfLeds22()));
```

They seems to be correct compared to my other connectors. A special thing is the class ledSetting in header, but its only used in this class and those connectors make no problems.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: You have a QPushButton* called connect in your code. Just change variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class has a `QPushButton*` named `connect` which hides the `connect()` function.

Hence the expression not being used as a function, because it is not a function !

Either rename the variable, or if not possible, you can call `QObject::connect()` explicitely to force the compiler to use the base class' version of `connect()`.

In addition, you can use (from Qt5 on) Qt's new connect syntax which lets the compiler do the type check for you. It uses function pointers instead of the `SIGNAL()` and `SLOT()` macros

```
QObject::connect( terminalCompleter, &QPlainTextEdit::textChanged, this, &settingWidget::onNrOfLeds22 );
```

Comment: many many thanks, so my qustion was unusefull (for others) at all.
sometimes it's like wearing the glass but searching them anyway..

Comment: i may forgot accept, but of course i wanna say "thank you" :)

also thanks for the Qt5-style-hint, i will use it!

1/2-offtopic: git commit -m "DO NOT CALL ANYTHING CONNECT!!!! continue work and fix a nasty connection-bug"